# "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1798

Tags: python, django

settings.py

```
# django.contrib.staticfiles включен INSTALLED_APPS.
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'project'
]
# Указание пути 
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

information.html

```
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Информация о человеке</title>
    <!-- Определение пути  к папке-->
    <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Имя:{{name}},  возраст: {{years}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

style.сss

```
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color:red;
}
```

Проблема:

> "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1798

Comment: Нет, только что попробовал. У меня новая проблема: " You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.".

Comment: Получилось.Можешь писать ответ

Comment: Просто комментарий нельзя отметить как ответ(вроде бы). Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно документации по [django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#deployment), необходимо указать в `settings.py` папку для обслуживания статических файлов и поместить в переменную `STATIC_ROOT`.

Пример:

```py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

Или можно указать другую директорию (из доки)

```py
STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/example.com/static/"
```

Далее выполните команду

```py
py manage.py collectstatic
```

Команда соберет все статические файлы проекта, включая статику `admin` панели.

Путь прописанный в переменной `STATIC_ROOT` нужно указать в веб-сервере, для обслуживания их.